# Qt 2D plotting with hardware acceleration using OpenGL v1.4?

Tags: qt, opengl, directx, qwt, qcustomplot

Our target system has an older graphic chip that only supports OpenGL 1.4. However, for a high scan rate 32K point oscilloscope-type plot, we really need hardware acceleration. Both QCustomPlot and QWT use the QPainter class that requires OpenGL ES 2.0 or later. Is there an easy way around this? Or, does anyone know of another plotting tool we can use that can hw accelerate on OpenGL 1.4? Our target is running QT 5.0 on Windows XP SP3.

```
for (int i=0; i<SCAN_SIZE; i++)
    m_plotQmap->insert(i,QCPData(i,lScanData[scan_dataset][i]));
ui->myPlot->graph(0)->setData(m_plotQmap,true);
ui->myPlot->replot();
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to plot all 32K points, for now. Using QCustomPlot, this takes takes 75msec. We need it to be maybe ten times faster.

Comment: Again, how big is the plot area? Width x height? How do you plot the "points"? Is there a symbol for each point (like a shape or a dot)? Are there lines joining the points?

Comment: The simplest way would be to use good old OpenGL directly, in a helper class. Personally, I'd probably do a port of QtQuick Scene Graph back to OpenGL 1.4 and use that - it'd be still *way* more flexible than a one-off solution, you could still have a decent, fluid user interface in addition to your plot.

Comment: Plot area is 750x450, it is a line plot with some symbols. We need a full featured plotting utility. Thanks for the interesting idea, but I'm looking for something easier. Our devices runs Windows XP, so a DirectX plug-in might also work.

Comment: What is your Qt version? How exactly do you use QCustomPlot? It might be possible to speed things up, the implementation leaves a bit to be desired. Please post a very minimal example of how you set up your plot, and how you update it. Feel free to generate random data.

Comment: Your chip may only support OpenGL 1.4, but if it supports DirectX 9.0c, it will likely run ANGLE, and you will get translated OpenGL ES 2 via Qt 5. Have you tried with Qt 5 and ANGLE?

Comment: Another cool idea I had not thought of, but our target has Windows XP which ANGLE supposedly does not run on well.

Comment: Try it out. There may be workarounds for the specific issues you may face. Do note that ANGLE is used by pretty much every Windows browser out there except for IE :)

Comment: I'd basically say this: use QCustomPlot or QWT, paint on an QGLWidget, use ANGLE, and see what you get.

Comment: I switched to Qt 5.1.1 ANGLE version and am now able to run additional Qt examples (2D Painting), but it does not help with QCustomPlot since that it not written with QGLxx classes. I downloaded Qt 4.8.5 and ran the program with the "-graphicssystem opengl" run argument. On my desktop computer, OpenGL kicked-in but only lowered the plot time from 42msec to 32msec. Our target computer gave me OpenGL errors. Looks like I'm on to a DirectX plug-in or hand-written OpenGL.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, single file example that shows how you use QCustomPlot? Just generate random data of same size in a few lines. I can profile it and see where the problem is.

Comment: Is there a standard place I can dump the project so you get the .h and .pro and all? It is a minimal project, written for benchmarking. Sorry for this non-contributing comment.

Comment: Pastebin or simply add it to the question by editing it. It should be just one .cpp file. Don't split it up. The .pro file is obvious unless you have something special there.

Answer (score 2):

For a target system with OpenGL 1.4 I recommend to use Qt4. It doesn't make any sense to use Qt5 when its minimum requirements are not satisfied. But with Qt4 everything should be fine with your platform.

Beside OpenGL the combination Qt4/X11 offers hardware accelerated graphics ( Qt5/X11 not ! ), but as you are on Windows ...

Qwt 6.1 introduced QwtPlotGLCanvas where you render with one of the OpenGL paint engines. In the refreshtest example you can check the effect of OpenGL and compare it with the sofware renderer ( set Updates to 0 ).

Also have a look at the oscilloscope example of Qwt that shows an implementation that incrementally paints a curve. When it is is possible to implement your plot this way you can have very high refresh rates - even with the software renderer.